# Is there any way to add a file field for multiple upload file to a custom form?

Tags: forms, files

I'd like to add a file upload widget to a custom form, with core file module, as shown in the admin edit node page. I've trying with the 'managed_file' API, but I've only got upload one file. I need multiple files and re-ordening.

Is there a way to use the File module in a custom form, as in the node edit form?

[image]